# How to get a object mask as part of the alpha channel?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, transparency

I am trying to get the middle sphere to render as a part of the alpha for the image. In the image below where I have the test grid image at the moment it really should be transparent. How do I do that?

[image: mask]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using cycles, all you have to do is use [holdout](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Shaders#Holdout) sahder node.
 Give the object that you want to have the 0 alpha a new material like this.
[image: nodes]
Then in the render tab of the properties window, under the *Film* section enable *Transparent*. You will have to save your render to a image format with a alpha channel, such as a `.png`.

Comment: Woah I never knew of that shader before, thanks a million David! That worked just right!

Answer (score 3):

These two nodes are all you need to add a object index pass to your render's alpha.
[image: nodes]
First the *ID Mask* gets the right object. The the *Mix* node combines the render's alpha with the object index. The Object Index pass returns a black and white image, so that is just mixed, using itself as the factor with the original alpha. Last plug the new alpha in to the *Alpha* socket on the *Composite* node.